# How do I get the Lightning Component "destroy" system event to fire?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events, aura-handler

I have a fairly bog standard Lightning Component with markup like:

```
<aura:component controller="MyController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,force:lightningQuickAction" >
    . . . 
    (omitted code)
    . . .
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:handler name="destroy" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleDestroy}"/>
    <aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleLocationChange}"/>
</aura:component>
```

and in my controller, actions which look like this:

```
({

    . . . omitted code . . .

    doInit: function( component, event, helper ) {

        console.log( "doInit" );

    },

    handleDestroy : function( component, event, helper ) {

        console.log( "handleDestroy" );                

    },

    handleLocationChange: function( component, event, helper ) {

        console.log( "location change" );        

    }

})
```

Both the "init" and "aura:locationChange" events fire and I see the console.log, but the "destroy" event never fires - even when i navigate away e.g. from "Cases" to "Reports" or to a different part of the system entirely.

I need to handle this event for removing event handlers attached to the window. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally when an component/app runs in LEX, it will not get destroyed as soon as you navigate to a different view. Have a look at the post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/157234/20830).
Also destroying component manually has a impact too which explained [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/160940/20830).

I believe action associated with `destroy` event will not be called immediately because of the component destroying issue in LEX.

The right place to remove the event listeners attached to window is in the `unrender`, which would be called only when the component/app is destroyed.

If `unrender` does not work properly(i.e due to the component destroying issue), you certainly use the `aura:locationChange` to remove the event listeners.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen - the event I am referring to is in the docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueDestroy.htm . Is that not a valid doc?

Comment: @goofballLogic Ah you are right, `destroy` event is present. I have amended my answer. With that said, background of the issue remains the same which is "component is not being destroyed upon navigation". It might take few navigations for the component to get destroyed, so I think we are better off doing the events removal in callback of `aura:locationChange`.

Comment: Above links in the answer details the component destroying issue.  I don't have a known issue link regarding it.