# How can I manage lightning components' navigation-related caching

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, cache

This is related to this question: [Navigation in Desktop Lightning Experience not Destroying Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/navigation-in-desktop-lightning-experience-not-destroying-components)

My components are listening to the force:refreshView event, but since the components are cached after navigation according to the question I linked, they still fire even when they are no longer on the page. This causes errors to show up.

I can't destroy them because then they do not reappear when using the back button to go to the previous page that used to contain my components.

Is there a way that I can detect if my components are currently being displayed on the page that fired the force:refreshView event?

UPDATE: As an intermediate solution, I'm checking `window.location.path` to see if it contains the name of the SObjectType these components can appear on before executing any other logic.

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var isOpportunityPage = path.includes('/Opportunity');

if(isOpportunityPage){
    // Do stuff here
}
```

This doesn't feel right at all, but it's something at least.